# Error writing to connection when merging large dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, merge, datatable

I am trying to join 80 dataframes together (each have 6 columns with an average of 14 million rows) on common fields (the first 3 columns of each dataframe). The list containing all 80 dataframes come up to be 37.8 GB. I am using my institution's high computing resource since the job is too big for my computer to process. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551433/speed-up-merging-many-dataframes-in-r) saying, data.table seems to perform the best so here's my code below:

```
library(data.table)
object_names <- ls() #get all the objects in the environment which are my 80 dfs
full <- mget(object_names) #make it into a list 
rm(list=ls(pattern="Lib_")) #remove original dataframes 
merge_columns <- c("Chromosome", "Start", "End") #columns im joining on
dt_list <- lapply(full, as.data.table) #convert to data.table
remove(full,object_names) #remove unnecessary objects taking up space
mydt <- function(...) merge(..., by=merge_columns, all=T)
FullDat <- Reduce(mydt, dt_list)
saveRDS(FullDat, "FullDat.rds") #save my final dataframe for later use
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Error in save(list = names(.GlobalEnv), file = outfile, version = version,  : 
  error writing to connection
Error saving session (search_path): Error in save(list = names(.GlobalEnv), file = outfile, version = version,  : 
  error writing to connection
```

I am not sure if this error is due to having not enough memory. I initially request 200GB memory for this R session.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: "error writing to connection" seems to imply you don't have permissions to write to the current working directory. If you just put `write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")` at the top of the script, does that work? Check the value of `getwd()` to see where R is trying to write files.

Comment: When I try to `saveRDS(..)` to a file within a non-existent directory, it errs with `cannot open the connection` (and warns `'No such file or directory'`); to an existing dir in which I do not have write-perms, errs with `cannot open the connection` (and `'Permission denied'`), and the same error messages when I try to overwrite a file for which I don't have write-perms. I don't know how to make it fail with _that_ error message. Is it a network path?

Comment: Having said that, your code uses `saveRDS` but the error lists `save(list=names(.GlobalEnv), ...)`. I don't think the former is merely a wrapper for the latter, so is there some other code that could be calling `save(.)`?